# How to execute functions sequentially using Node Js Promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I'm new to Node js Promise I'm not sure whether I'm using the Promise correctly or not so here is my code.

```
function print(){

    first('first')
    .then(second('second'))
    .then(third('third'));
}

function first(a){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var res1 = function (){
            resolve(a);
        }    
    });
    console.log(a);
}

function second(b){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var res1 = function (){
            resolve(b);
        }    
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(b);
    }, 2000);
}

function third(c){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var res1 = function (){
            resolve(c);
        }    
    });
    console.log(c);
}
```

My desired output is

```
first
second
third
```

Instead what I get is

```
first
third
//after two seconds
second
```

I'm missing something but I can't figure it out please explain me

Comment: then expects a function as it's argument(s) - not the result of running a function!

Comment: You code doesn't produce ANY output - it's syntactically wrong in every function and has unreachable code in first, second and third - and none of first, second or third would ever resolve either ... more wrong than right in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the expected behaviour, you need to `resolve` inside of the timeout (next to the console log). You also cannot pass arguments into promise chain functions since they need to accept the promise from the previous thennable.

A working snippet is below:

```js
print();

function print(){
    first('first')
    .then(second)
    .then(third);
}

function first(a){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(a);
        resolve(a);  
    });
}

function second(b){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("second");
        resolve(b);
      }, 2000);  
    });

}

function third(c){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log("third"); 
        resolve(c)
    });
}
```